# ExecutorService: What happens if I submit() way too many tasks to the Executor?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

Looks like ExecutorService internally uses a blocking queue.

I am assigning only 2 threads to the ExecutorService like so:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

What happens if I keep on submitting tasks endlessly? Will the blocking queue prevent more tasks from adding if it is full? Will the memory be hampered by the submission of so many tasks? What are the implications? Asking because I am seeing this happening in my code so want to know what are the side-effects.

```
Future<> future = executorService.submit(callableTask);
```

Comment: "Will the blocking queue prevent more tasks from adding if it is full?": yes, that's what "blocking queue" means.

Comment: no?? a blocking queue is a queue that supports operations that waits for the queue to become non-empty. It MAY be optionally bounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the implementation of `ExecutorSevice` inside of static method like `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`

```java
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, 
                                  nThreads,
                                  0L, 
                                  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

and the corresponding constructors for `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `LinkedBlockingQueue` are below.

```java
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                          int maximumPoolSize,
                          long keepAliveTime,
                          TimeUnit unit,
                          BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
   this(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,
         Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), defaultHandler);
}
```

```java
public LinkedBlockingQueue() {
   this(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Consequently, if you continue to submit tasks to the thread pool (assuming that the tasks you submit take a significant amount of time), it may eventually lead to an OutOfMemoryError (OOM).

However, without knowing the specific situation you are facing, I would not recommend replacing it with `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` since it will keep creating new threads.

Instead, I would advise you to create your own `ThreadPoolExecutor` tailored to your needs.

Comment: oooh, i didnt know linkedblockingqueue also had a limit of Integer.MAX_VALUE. I thought it was like a linked list

Comment: @experimentunit1998X in what regard do you consider this to be different to linked list?

Comment: @Holger at first I made a comment about how LinkedBlockingQueue could just keep sending/submitting until it reaches the limit of the resources provided to it or possibly infinitely because it did not have a bound like ArrayBlockingQueue which uses an array (indices go up to Integer.MAX_VALUE), I thought this had no upper bound like a linked list

Comment: I am aware that LinkedBlockingQueue has an optional bound that can be specified, but I didnt know that LinkedBlockingQueue itself imposes a bound of Integer.MAX_VALUE if not specified

Comment: The limit of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is obviously meant to be “practically no limit”. This means that if you ever managed to put `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements into it and try to add one more, it will surprisingly block whereas adding more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements to a `LinkedList` will silently corrupt it. Thankfully, the chances of ever getting to this point are very low.

Answer (score 2):

As the Javadocs for `newFixedThreadPool()` states:

```
newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)
Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.
```

Note the unbounded part.  Thread pool executors leave the handling of queue limits to the `BlockingQueue` assigned to them.  Giving an unbounded queue means the executor will never reject a task.  However, it also means you will happily run your JVM out of heap if there is too much load.

Using a blocking queue with a limit will lead to tasks being rejected by the executor when total queue size + total thread limits are reached.